# Sending an HTTPS Request from an Azure Function to an external Web Service using a Certificate

Tags: azure, azure-functions, invoke-restmethod, certificate-authentication

A hearty hello to everyone!

I have set up an Azure Function App (S1 SKU) and I am trying to use one of the functions as a client that sends an HTTPS-Request to another web server (API).
I do this using the Powershell Cmdlet Invoke-RestMethod which I provide with a certificate in order to authenticate my request to the web server. (This certificate has been added to the trusted certificates of the web server's cert store.)

```
$cert = Get-AzKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName $keyVaultName -Name $certificateLabel
Invoke-RestMethod -Method 'GET' -URI $URI -Certificate $cert.Certificate
```

Where $cert.Certificate is a X509Certificate2 object.
However, I am unable to establish trust between the two parties because the SSL validation yields: UntrustedRoot.
Here is the exception I get when calling Invoke-RestMethod:

```
"The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: UntrustedRoot"
```

I understand why this occurs. Unlike classic servers, "serverless" Azure functions have no certificate store that checks for certificates for validity. Thus I cannot upload the trusted root and intermediate certificates.

How do I establish trust for the root and intermediate certificates in this case?

When presenting ChatGPT with this problem, it suggested implementing a custom ssl validation callback that handles the trust validation. But it also warned of using this in a production environment as the validation procedure should be carefully implemented.

Is there another workaround or a thorough guide for custom ssl validation callbacks?

Thank you very much for your time in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with skipping the certificate check, just to crack on with the rest of the coding.

```
$cert = Get-AzKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName $keyVaultName -Name $certificateLabel
Invoke-RestMethod -SkipCertificateCheck -Method 'GET' -URI $URI -Certificate $cert.Certificate
```

ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-7.3